# jQuery 1.6.4 and RadioButtonList issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

Moving from jQuery 1.4.4 to jquery 1.6.4 started breaking my code related to radiobuttonlist.

Here is a sample code and steps to replicate weird behavior:

Steps to reproduce:

1: Radio A is already selected.

2: Select radio B

3: Enter something in textbox and tab out.

You will see: **A is checked and B is checked alerts.**

So what exactly changed from 1.6.4 to 1.4.4 that is causing it to break?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
        <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function txtchanged(tb) {
            $(".rbl").find("input[type='radio']").each(function () {
                alert($(this).val() + " " + $(this).attr("checked"));
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" CssClass="rbl">
        <asp:ListItem Text="A" Value="A" Selected="True" />
         <asp:ListItem Text="B" Value="B" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tb" runat="server" CssClass="tb" onblur="txtchanged(this)"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> So what exactly changed from 1.6.4 to 1.4.4 that is causing it to
>   break?

Radio button `checked` is not an attribute, it's a property. jQuery was updated in version 1.6 to correct this semantic error.

Change this...

```
.attr("checked")
```

to this...

```
.prop("checked")
```

**EDITS:**

As to the OP's comment about why jQuery is not backward compatible:

1)  It would add an accumulation of bloat to the code.

2)  To be *"backward compatible"* would be virtually the same as not fixing this problem at all.

[See this page to read the release notes on every version of jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Current_Release).

Also change this...

```
.removeAttr('checked')
```

to this...

```
.removeProp('checked')
```

Comment: yep got that but then the question is I will have to find and change all such instances and making sure nothing else breaks. Why isn't this backward compatible. I even noticed that removeAttr('checked') in my code is also screwed up when using 1.6.4.

Comment: @gbs, see my updated answer.  You only ask one very specific question and I answered it correctly.  Your follow-up question is why many people stick with their current version of jQuery.  It's impossible for me to know what other instance or situations might break on your particular site but follow the [link](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Current_Release) I posted to read about what other things have changed since version 1.4.4.